# Dynamically Adding inputs in Angular 1.3.16

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

My Code is simple and as I searched on net, I guess it is because of angular 1.3.x
I am trying to create dynamic inputs and want to get the value in an array.
HTML:

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="item in designFormData.perInstallments track by $index">
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <label for="">Installment #{{item.sn}}</label>
    </div>
    <!-- /.col-xs-6 col-sm-4 -->
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="" autocomplete="off" ng-model="item.price">
    </div>
    <!-- /.col-xs-6 col-sm-4 -->
</div>
```

JS:

```
for (var i = 0; i < noOfInstallments; i++) {
    $scope.designFormData.perInstallments.push({
        sn: i+2,
        price: ""
    });
}
```

Problem:
The price is not reflecting in perInstallments

```
designFormData{
 perInstallments:
[
 {
   sn: 2,
   price: ""
 },
 {
   sn: 2,
   price: ""
 }
]
}
```

values, instead of appearing in perInstallments items, are appearing in child scope of ng-repeat. how to solve this. I have tried adding track by $index as you can see.

Any suggestions.

Comment: What does `appearing in child scope` mean? Not clear what issue is.  Create a demo that replicates whatever problem you see.   A better explanation would also help

Comment: @charlietfl: have changed it

Comment: Have no idea what you are asking or what the problem is.